# Grub Customizer Crashes, reset Grub settings

Tags: ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-12.04

I have a problem with Grub Customizer, I installed it and re-installed it, but every time I run it, it crushes before I can do anything. The thing is my Grub 2 Bootloader now is full with previous versions of Ubuntu and Recovery files. Is there a way I can find out why Grub Customizer is crushing ?  How can I properly reset all grub/boot settings to default ?

---

Getting also this problem report when I start Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 Bit

[image]
[image]

---

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Ubuntu Update, Grub Customizer was crashing, I could not change the grub settings. I cleared all the dependencies and updated my Grub2 through the command line. It did not help. But then i started to open many instances of Grub Customizer, after 3,4 one did not crash and i got a massage that a new script was found you wanna save ? So I saved. Now Grub Customizer is working fine again.